# Google app engine this application does not exist error

Tags: google-app-engine, rollback, appcfg

I use java backend on google's appengine with eclipse sdk.
When I tried to update my backend with eclipse, i got error that says

> com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: >https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=infra-filament-610&version=2&
>   409 Conflict
>   Another transaction by user heodong91 is already in progress for app: s~infra-filament-610, version: 2. >That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".

So I ran the rollback on terminal with command

> appcfg.sh rollback /Users/Donghyeok/PlanItBackend/src/main/webapp

but its giving me this error

> Unable to rollback app: Error posting to URL: httpsds://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/rollback?>app_id=infra-filament-610&version=2&
>   404 Not Found
>   This application does not exist (app_id=u'infra-filament-610').

So then I looked up possible solutions and ran this on the command line.

appcfg.sh --no_cookies rollback /Users/Donghyeok/PlanItBackend/src/main/webapp

It still gave me the same error

This is try #3
Unable to rollback app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/rollback?app_id=infra-filament-610&version=2&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'infra-filament-610').

I tried again with --oauth2 option and still give me the same error.

I also tried removing .appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java file but same error.

I have tried many things in many combinations but I wasn't able to solve this issue. So the main problem is the first one. But to solve this I had to rollback, but its not letting me rollback.
Could someone please help?
I'm like desperate...

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm having the exact same problem. `404 Not Found, application doesn't exist`. As with you, it says `(app_id=u'xxx-xxx-xxx')`. I'm wondering where the `u'` is coming from.. Could it be that?

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by changing the app name in app.yaml to the name of the project (visible in Google Developer Console, often suffixed with a number). It may also work by simply adding at the end of your rollback command line the following:

```
--application=<projectname>
```

Regards